# Text Fields hidden behind keyboard

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm developing a login page and the username and password text fields are in the middle of the screen. The problem is when I select the password text field the keyboard covers it.

So, how can I make sure a TextField is visible in the viewport when it has the focus without being covered by the keyboard? I want the page to go up when I open the keyboard and to the normal position when I close the keyboard.

Developed Code (TextField sample):

```dart
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Password',
    labelStyle: TextStyle(
       fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
       color: Colors.blue
    )    
  ),
  obscureText: true
),
```

I saw this issue in the GitHub page but was closed without solution: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19300

I also found some workaround but seems to work only with scrollable pages:
https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/04/hint-4-ensure-a-textfield-or-textformfield-is-visible-in-the-viewport-when-has-the-focus/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should add a scrollcontainer

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to `Scaffold`

Comment: Thanks! The problem was related to the column alignment. I defined a hardcoded alignment and when I added your property suggestion, the page returned an error saying: "Bottom overflowed by X pixels". So, this made me look to the page alignment and ..... problem solved. I don't need your property suggestion, only the correct page alignment.